# Cleaning out the garage

Tags: word, pattern, word-property

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #12: mobile-friendly puzzles](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7484/monthly-topic-challenge-12-mobile-friendly-puzzles).</sub>

---

I really need to clean out my garage - it's so full, it often feels like it contains one of everything. Today when I opened it up it contained:

> A pleasant smell,
> (A postcard from) a German town on the White Elster river,
> A bird of prey,
> An implement for shaving,
> The text from the back of a book,
> A lemur,
> (A trading card depicting) a Montreal Canadiens player,
> A tough, elastic, synthetic polymer,
> A children’s magazine,
> An Australian freshwater crayfish,
> A Celtic priest,
> A tranquiliser,
> (A small replica of) an Australian landmark,
> A price tag,
> Grilled bread,
> An accumulation of fabric fibres,
> A woman whose spouse has died,
> (A piece of music by) a Norwegian composer,
> (A postcard from) an Italian commune in the Province of Ancona,
> A pair of glasses,
> A small, benign growth,
> (A postcard from) a village in the Jihlava District of Czechia,
> Bootleg alcohol,
> A device for converting digital information into analogue signals,
> A Russian coin...

There was another coin as well, but the motion of the door opening caused it to roll away.

**Can you help me remember what it was?**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

My answer is:

> `QEPIQ`  A coin worth 1/100 of a *manat* in  Azerbaijan
>
>  Please see [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/qepiq)
>  and [Origins of World Currency Names](https://www.theibns.org/joomla/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=5&Itemid=28)
>
>  These are 25 five-letter words with the same first and last letter.
>  The unused letter must be the answer.
>
>  `AROMA`  A pleasant smell,
>  `ZEITZ`  (A postcard from) a German town on the White Elster river,
>  `EAGLE`  A bird of prey,
>  `RAZOR`  An implement for shaving,
>  `BLURB`  The text from the back of a book,
>  `INDRI`  A lemur,
>  `JURAJ`  (A trading card depicting) a Montreal Canadiens player,
>  `NYLON`  A tough, elastic, synthetic polymer,
>  `COMIC`  A children’s magazine,
>  `YABBY`  An Australian freshwater crayfish,
>  `DRUID`  A Celtic priest,
>  `XANAX`  A tranquiliser,
>  `ULURU`  (A small replica of) an Australian landmark,
>  `LABEL`  A price tag,
>  `TOAST`  Grilled bread,
>  `FLUFF`  An accumulation of fabric fibres,
>  `WIDOW`  A woman whose spouse has died,
>  `GRIEG`  (A piece of music by) a Norwegian composer,
>  `OSIMO`  (A postcard from) an Italian commune in the Province of Ancona,
>  `SPECS`  A pair of glasses,
>  `POLYP`  A small, benign growth,
>  `VANOV`  (A postcard from) a village in the Jihlava District of Czechia,
>  `HOOCH`  Bootleg alcohol,
>  `MODEM`  A device for converting digital information into analogue signals,
>  `KOPEK`  A Russian coin...
>
>  So the unused letter is Q

Postscript following Stiv's comment:

> The initial (and last) letters of the first eight answers spells
>
>  **AZERBIJN**
>
>  Of course the repeated letters are dropped as the answers contain only one of each.

Comment: Great work, all correct! Can/Did you spot the extra clue hidden in the first rows of answers?